# Select Cells With Empty Value

Tags: vba, excel, null, cell

I'm creating a VBA script to color up some specifics cells, so far its going well, but now I need it to color some cells that have an empty value. These cells aren't blanks, they have formulas, but sometimes that formula will return "" as value. I need to select these specific cells, how can I do that?

Once again, these cells aren't empty or blank, only their value is null.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's what you want:

- `IsEmpty(ActiveCell)` Checks if the cell is completely empty. No Formula or data whatsoever.
- `ActiveCell.Value=""` Checks if the result of the cell is blank. (Blank data can be returned by a formula in the cell)

So if you want to check if the cell value is blank but there is a formula would be `Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And ActiveCell.Value = ""`

---

**EDIT**

Following clarification in comment the code would be:

```
Sub SelectEmpty()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Range("B18:H18")
        If Cell.Value = "" Then
            If MyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set MyRange = Cell
            Else
                Set MyRange = Application.Union(MyRange, Cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    MyRange.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Its like that (ActiveCell.Value = ""), but how do I select only these cells? Like, in the Range(B18:H18) I have some cells with blank value others with value, I want to select only the ones with blank value, how do I do that?

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio I added the code in my answer that would select empty valued cells from a range.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of those cells, empty or "" with Conditional Formatting.

Insert a new rule, choose the option

```
Use a formula to determine wich values to format
```

And then write the formula:

```
=TRIM(B18)=""
```